# Keep the format when output is copied and pasted

Tags: output-formatting

I have an output and I would like to copy and paste it into another .nb file.

[image]

When I copy paste using Ctrl+c and Ctrl+v. I get

[image]

When I copy paste using Ctrl+Shift+c and Ctrl+v. I get

[image]

Or When I use `NumberForm` I get this. I would like to plot the function after I copied it and pasted it.

[image]
Question is: Is there a way keep the format (rational form like second image) and keep the number format like the third image when I copy paste the formula.

Here is the function,

```
133.59 + (582.132 i2^1.35153)/(0.428001 + i2^1.35153) + (
 6603.52 i1^0.992746 i2^1.35153)/((0.0109047 + 
    i1^0.992746) (0.428001 + i2^1.35153))

133.58951900651672` + (582.1322741801231` i2^1.3515291336147885`)/(
 0.4280007641806738` + i2^1.3515291336147885`) + (
 6603.519187497128` i1^0.9927463133595625` \
i2^1.3515291336147885`)/((0.010904677243932988` + 
    i1^0.9927463133595625`) (0.4280007641806738` + 
    i2^1.3515291336147885`))
```

Comment: When I entered your equation, I got the same results as your first pasting.
Can it be that the default numbering displays are different? edit->preferences->formatting->number of digits displayed

Comment: I think its important to think about why you want this.   There is a good reason for Mathematica to keep all of those digits.

Comment: Of course it is important to keep all digits, but I am not working on a space project and plotting function in first image and function in second image are identical. New notebook looks busy when I keep all digits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are seeing is the effect of the option `NumberMarks`, which is set to `True` in "Input" cells and "False" in "Output" cells.  If you wish to disable it in a particular "Input" cell to match an "Output" cell, do the following (there are many other ways of doing this)

1. Select the cell
2. Open the Option Inspector (Shift+Cntrl/Cmd+O, depending on your platform)
3. Search for NumberMarks
4. Uncheck the box.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using one of the "Form" functions such as `StandardForm` or `NumberForm`

[image]