# Copy-paste with annoying trailing 0s

Tags: output-formatting, machine-precision

When one copies an output containing machine-precision numbers to a input, many trailing 0s appears.

For example :

Evaluate the following expression :

```
{{41.`,19.200000000000003`},
 {41.`,39.5`},
 {33.6`,49.300000000000004`},
 {33.2`,59.800000000000004`}, 
 {33.2`,61.800000000000004`}}
```

> {{41., 19.2}, {41., 39.5}, {33.6, 49.3}, {33.2, 59.8}, {33.2, 61.8}}

Then copy-paste this output. The result is a input cell with again all the trailing 0s.

I need to Round the values so that the input form stays short (It
 is not a problem of number formatting/rendering since the numerical values can be changed a little bit in this operation).

**Tests already done, without success :**

First, a preamble that shows that this is possible

```
niceValue=49.3
niceValue //InputForm
```

> 49.3
>   49.3

Then, a example of a difficult case :

```
irritatingValue=49.300000000000004`  
irritatingValue //InputForm
```

> 49.3
>   49.300000000000004

Unsuccessfull attempts :

This seems to work :

```
Round[irritatingValue,1. 10^-6] //InputForm
```

> 49.3

But this does not :

```
Round[irritatingValue,1. 10^-5] //InputForm
```

> 49.300000000000004

so the "solution" `Round[..., 1. 10^-n]` is inacceptable. Because the problem is certainly due to the binary representation of numbers that we see ultimately in base 10, I have tried also things like : `Round[..., 256 $MachineEpsilon]` and `Round[..., 2^-10]` , without success.

`Chop[...]` doesn't seem neither to bring a solution.

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve? The numbers carrying over the extra 0's in copy pastes?

Comment: Yes. When I copy-paste long list of numbers, the pasted expression is too long, too difficult to read...

Comment: Why not use copy as plain text instead (keyboard shortcut on MacOS is Shift-Cmd-C)?

Comment: Your irritating value differs from the closest binary representation of `49.3` by 3 ulp, which I suppose is due to floating-point rounding error, if indeed the result is supposed to be `49.3`. If so, it's not because of the limitations of the binary representation of numbers, other than rounding error. Something similar happens with `0.3` vs. `3 * 0.1`.

Comment: Have you seen this https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/175308/23291

Comment: Just give them a name. Then use them by calling the name instead of by copying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In[1]:= {{41.`, 19.200000000000003`}, {41.`, 39.5`}, {33.6`, 
  49.300000000000004`}, {33.2`, 59.800000000000004`}, {33.2`, 
  61.800000000000004`}}

Out[1]= {{41., 19.2}, {41., 39.5}, {33.6, 49.3}, {33.2, 59.8}, {33.2, 
  61.8}}
```

`ToString`:

```
In[2]:= ToString@%

Out[2]= "{{41., 19.2}, {41., 39.5}, {33.6, 49.3}, {33.2, 59.8}, \
{33.2, 61.8}}"
```

`ToExpression`:

```
In[3]:= ToExpression@%

Out[3]= {{41., 19.2}, {41., 39.5}, {33.6, 49.3}, {33.2, 59.8}, {33.2, 
  61.8}}
```

Comment: Unexpected approach, but it seems to do the job for my initial problem. Nevertheless, I need to do more tests tomorrow.

Comment: @Carl Woll's suggestion to copy as plain text is valid too.